# Need similar routing configuration for area as with normal routing configuration

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am using `ASP.NET MVC3`. I am trying to configure my routes but there seems to be conflicting routes. Not sure how to fix it, hoping that someone can point me in the right direction.

I have 2 sections in my website where applications can be viewed. A normal user of the website can view only his/her applications.  And an administrator can view the all the applications that were captured by using the administration area.

Notes can be added to an already existing application. Notes are just additional information that can be captured at any time during the process of the application.  I am looking to display all the notes already captured for an application like this:

```
/Application/1001/Notes
/Administration/Application/1001/Notes
```

This is how I configured my routes:

```
Routes.MapRoute(
     "ApplicationNote",
     "{controller}/{applicationId}/Notes",
     new { controller = "Application", action = "Notes" },
     new { applicationId = @"\d+" },
     new[] { "MyProject.Web.Controllers" });

Routes.MapRoute(
     "AdminApplicationNote",
     "{area}/{controller}/{applicationId}/Notes",
     new { area = "Administration", controller = "Application", action = "Notes" },
     new { applicationId = @"\d+" },
     new[] { "MyProject.Web.Areas.Administration.Controllers" });
```

To display the first link (next to each application in the data table) I have the following in my controller that will generate the action link for each record:

```
string actionLinks = string.Empty;
actionLinks += "<a href=\"" + Url.Action("Notes", "Application", new { area = string.Empty, applicationId = application.Id }) + "\">" + "Notes</a>";
```

The second link I display like this (from my controller action, same as above):

```
string actionLinks = string.Empty;
actionLinks = "<a href=\"" + Url.Action("Notes", new { applicationId = application.Id, area = "Administration", controller = "Application" }) + "\">" + "Notes</a>";
```

The first configuration works well:

```
/Application/1001/Notes
```

...but the second not so well.  When I hover over the link of the second configuration then the status shows:

```
/Administration/Application/Notes?applicationId=1001
```

What am I doing wrong with the admin area's route configuration?

Comment: Strange. I wonder if applicationID constraint is honored even if it's not in the specified segment. Can you try http://example.org/Administration/Application/Notes and see which action runs?

Comment: @Brendan Vogt  do you've solved the admin area's route configuration? do you've found a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Add Constraint area = string.Empty

```
   routes.MapRoute(
        "ApplicationNote",
        "{controller}/{applicationId}/Notes",
        new { controller = "Application", action = "Notes" }, 
        new { applicationId = @"\d+", area = string.Empty }, //<----
        new[] { "MyProject.Web.Controllers" }
   );
```